# How to generate a random number from whole range of int in C?

Tags: c, random

```
unsigned const number = minimum + (rand() % (maximum - minimum + 1))
```

I know how to (easily) generate a random number within a range such as from 0 to 100. But what about a random number from the **full range** of `int` (assume `sizeof(int) == 4`), that is from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`, both inclusive?

I don't need this for cryptography or the like, but a approximately uniform distribution would be nice, and I need *a lot* of those numbers.

The approach I'm currently using is to generate 4 random numbers in the range from 0 to 255 (inclusive) and do some messy casting and bit manipulations. I wonder whether there's a better way.

Comment: No, but apparently my google foo is lacking? If this is so straight forward, then please, just answer.

Comment: @DanielJour He's been like this all day.

Comment: You're doing great: just pay attention to negative numbers. You don't want to do binary operations (or, xor, and) with negative numbers.

Comment: @Olaf Pseudo random is ok for me.

Comment: Dear downvoters: Please explain why you downvote me. In case that there is already a similar question on SO, please link to it. (I searched a lot)

Comment: You can obtain several "random" numbers and shift, mask, OR etc, with your greater bit width. On my system `RAND_MAX` is `32767`, ie the value is 15 bit.

Comment: Check the [man page for rand](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) - it returns a value between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, which happens to be `INT_MAX` on my system - so you're just 1 bit short.

Comment: @Kenney Yeah, but `RAND_MAX` could be as low as `32767` .. then I'm still missing 17 bit.

Comment: Grab an external library, perhaps even my own ojrandlib.

Comment: @DanielJour Do you have access to [`arc4random()`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/arc4random.3?query=arc4random&sec=3) on your system, there is no tag for the language or platform. It returns a 32-bit unsigned value that is cryptographically secure and requires no salting..

Comment: Concerning DV, weaknesses to this question include: 1) Great title yet than only a subset of possible `int` "assume sizeof(int) == 4" requested. 2) "approach I'm currently using" describes your code - better to post your code in the quesiton. 3) Accepted answer gives an `unsigned` result and so glosses over issues of  bringing it into `int` and `[INT_MIN INT_MAX]` range (with potential non 2's complement - uniformity issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system `RAND_MAX` is 32767 which is 15 bits. So for a 32-bit `unsigned` just call three times and shift, or, mask etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned rando, i;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rando = ((unsigned)rand() << 17) | ((unsigned)rand() << 2) | ((unsigned)rand() & 3);
        printf("%u\n", rando);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
3294784390
3748022412
4088204778
```

Comment: Ok, I'm doing something similar atm, but this is better, because IIRC `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to have at least 15 bits. (I'm only using 8 of these)

Comment: This is not portable.

Comment: When `RAND_MAX` is not 32767, `((unsigned)rand() << 17) | ((unsigned)rand() << 2) | ...` is very bad code for random numbers.  This code should adjust for `RAND_MAX` or `assert/_Static_assert` that condition.

Comment: @chux it would be better using `^` instead of `|`

Answer (score 1):

For reference I'm adding what I've been using:

```
int random_int(void) {
  assert(sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(int));
  unsigned int accum = 0;
  size_t i = 0;
  for (; i < sizeof(int); ++i) {
    i <<= 8;
    i |= rand() & 0x100;
  }
  // Attention: Implementation defined!
  return (int) accum;
}
```

But I like Weather Vane's solution better because it uses fewer `rand()` calls and thus makes more use of the (hopefully good) distribution generated by it.

Comment: A stronger qualification test uses `UINT_MAX, INT_MAX, INT_MIN` than `assert(sizeof(unsigned int)...`.  It can also be used in macro pre-processing so as to not compile rather than fail at run time.  Still a good basic approach.  (Should have had this code in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

We should be able to do something that works no matter what the range of `rand()` or what size result we're looking for just by accumulating enough bits to fill a given type:

```c
// can be any unsigned type.
typedef uint32_t uint_type;
#define RAND_UINT_MAX ((uint_type) -1)

uint_type rand_uint(void)
{
    // these are all constant and factor is likely a power of two.
    // therefore, the compiler has enough information to unroll
    // the loop and can use an immediate form shl in-place of mul.
    uint_type factor = (uint_type) RAND_MAX + 1;
    uint_type factor_to_k = 1;
    uint_type cutoff = factor ? RAND_UINT_MAX / factor : 0;
    uint_type result = 0;

    while ( 1 ) {
        result += rand() * factor_to_k;
        if (factor_to_k <= cutoff)
            factor_to_k *= factor;
        else
            return result;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Makes the minimum number of calls to `rand()` necessary to populate all bits.

Let's [verify](http://ideone.com/WdEJNo) this gives a uniform distribution.

At this point we could just cast the result of `rand_uint()` to type *int* and be done, but it's more useful to get output in a specified range. The problem is: How do we reach `INT_MAX` when the operands are of type *int*?

Well... We can't. We'll need to use a type with greater range:

```
int uniform_int_distribution(int min, int max)
{
    // [0,1) -> [min,max]
    double canonical = rand_uint() / (RAND_UINT_MAX + 1.0);
    return floor(canonical * (1.0 + max - min) + min);
}
```

As a final note, it may be worthwhile to implement the random function in terms of type *double* instead, i.e., accumulate enough bits for `DBL_MANT_DIG` and return a result in the range *[0,1)*. In fact this is what `std::generate_canonical` does.