# Calculate dynamic range of rand with mod

Tags: c, random, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I want to create a rand() range between 1 and the dynamic value of `bit_cnt`.

After reading more about the rand() function, I understand that out of the box rand() has a range of [0, RAND_MAX]. I also understand that RAND_MAX's value is library-dependent, but is guaranteed to be at least 32767.

I had to create a bit mask of 64 0s.

Now, I am trying to left shift the bit mask by a dynamic value of `bit_cnt` anded with the a randomly generated number of bits between 1 and the dynamic value of `bit_cnt`.

For example, when `bit_cnt` is 10, I want to randomize the lowest 10 bits.

Originally, I had

```
mask = (mask << bit_cnt) + (rand()% bit_cnt);
```

which caused a floating point exception. From what I am understanding, that exception occurred because the value of `bit_cnt`became 0.

Therefore, I attempted to create an if statement like this:

```
if((rand()%bit_cnt))!=0){
 mask = (mask << bit_cnt) + (rand()% bit_cnt);
}
```

,but the floating point exception still occurred.

Then I tried the following thinking that the value not be 0 so increase the value to at least 1:

```
mask = (mask << bit_cnt) + ((rand()% bit_cnt)+1);
```

,but the floating point exception still occurred.

Afterwards, I tried the following:

```
mask = (mask << bit_cnt) + (1+(rand()%(bit_cnt+1)));
```

and the following 20 lines of 64 bits outputted:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000110
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100001001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000001001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000001111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000001010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000001101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000001100
```

What was the cause of the floating point exception? Is this how to dynamic create a range of the rand() function?

I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

UPDATE:
I changed the if statement to be the following:

```
if(bit_cnt !=0)
```

and then performed the rest of the logic.

I received the following output:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000110
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000001000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000110
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000110
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000001100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000001101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000110
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000010000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000100
```

Is there any possible way to know if the range is correct? Like is there any possible way to know by looking at the output?

```
const int LINE_CNT = 20;
void print_bin(uint64_t num, unsigned int bit_cnt);
uint64_t rand_bits(unsigned int bit_cnt);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < LINE_CNT; i++) {
        uint64_t val64 = rand_bits(i);
        print_bin(val64, 64);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void print_bin(uint64_t num, unsigned int bit_cnt) {

    int top_bit_cnt;

    if(bit_cnt <= 0) return;
    if(bit_cnt > 64) bit_cnt = 64;

    top_bit_cnt = 64;
    while(top_bit_cnt > bit_cnt) {
        top_bit_cnt--;
        printf(" ");
    }

    while(bit_cnt > 0) {
        bit_cnt--;
        printf("%d", (num & ((uint64_t)1 << bit_cnt)) != 0);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
uint64_t rand_bits(unsigned int bit_cnt) {
    uintmax_t mask = 1;
    if (bit_cnt != 0) {
        mask = (mask << bit_cnt) + (rand()% bit_cnt);
    }
    return mask;
}
```

I am trying to modify the function rand_bits to return all 0 expect for the lowest bits aka `bit_cnt` which are randomized.
Returns a 64 bit pattern with all zeros except for the lowest requested bits, which are randomized.  This allows for arbitrary length random bit patterns in a portable fashion as the C standard "rand()" function is only required to return
random numbers between 0 and 32767... effectively, a random 15 bit pattern.
Parameter, "bit_cnt":  How many of the lowest bits, including the lowest order bit (bit 0) to be randomized.

UPDATE: Added Barmar's newest suggestion of `mask = rand() % (1 << bit_cnt);`:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010101001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101101100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101011111000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001010101111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011101011000101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001101111101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111000000111010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101100000001100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100111101000111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010101011101000110



uint64_t rand_bits(unsigned int bit_cnt) {
            uintmax_t mask = 1;
    if (bit_cnt != 0) {
    mask = rand() % (1 << bit_cnt);
    }
    return mask;
    }
```

Comment: Recently [answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490210/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-whole-range-of-int-in-c/35490477#35490477) which although was commented as non-portable, you could adapt to 64-bit int.

Comment: What does floating point have to do with the question? And.. since the question update, if only the lowest bits are random, what relevance is 64-bit? If you want just the lowest bits randomised, mask `rand()` with `1`, `3`, `7`, `15` etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane I looked at the code in the other question. In your code, can you please explain where the values: 17, 2 and 3 are coming from? Thank you. Also, I ran into a floating point exception because the mod function on rand() became 0. With update, where are the values 1, 3, 7 and 15 coming from?

Comment: They are to align a 15 bit result with a 32-bit variable. Shift 17 for the ms 15 bits, shift 2 for the next ls 15 bits, leaves 2 bits, hence `&3` which is the two least bits, binary `11`

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You say you want a random number between `1` and `bit_cnt`. So when `bit_cnt` is `10`, you'll get something from `1` to `10`. Did you really mean you want to randomize all 10 low-order bits? That's not the same thing at all.

Comment: In that case, you should use `% expt(2, bit_cnt)`.

Comment: @Weather Vane "What does floating point have to do with the question?" --> Integer div by 0 or `% 0` is often reported by the system as a FP problem.

Comment: @Barmar What is expt? Yes, I mean randomize all 10 low-order bits if `bit_cnt` is say 10.

Comment: @Justin_Finland the 1, 3, 7, 15, are bit masks (binary) `1`, `11`, `111`, `1111`. If you want the lowest 3 bits random, you would use `rand() & 7` to mask off all but the lowest 3 bits.

Comment: @Justin_Finland Sorry, meant `pow()`.

Comment: But for integers you can just use `rand() % (1 << bit_cnt)`

Comment: Masking, and modulus, are similar for powers of 2. `42 % 8` is 2. `42 & 7` is 2.

Comment: @Barmar No problem, sir. `bit_cnt` is an unsigned int so I implemented what you just suggested. Please see my edit as I have output and am not sure if I should be keeping the original number that the mask was set to. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear: `% 0` , `/ 0` ,  `(uint64_t)1 << 64` are all problems.  Do not let that happen.

Comment: @WeatherVane `bit_cnt`: How many of the lowest bits, including the lowest order bit (bit 0) to be randomized.

Comment: Some `rand()` implementations (one of the BSDs I think) have very poor behavior in the low order bits. The low-order N bits repeat every 2**N calls, so for example the results alternate odd, even, odd, even, .... Most implementations don't have this problem. See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), questions 13.16 and 13.18. If you care about the quality of your random numbers, you should probably use something other than `rand()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `anything % bit_cnt` will get an error if `bit_cnt` is `0`. You need to check `bit_cnt` **before** you try to perform the modulus.

```
if (bit_cnt != 0) {
    mask = (mask << bit_cnt) + (rand()% bit_cnt) + 1;
}
```

All your attempts performed the modulus and then tried to do something with the result, but that's after the error happens.

Comment: I don't see how the output relates to the question. Where are those numbers coming from, and what determines whether you display 32 or 64 digits?

Comment: Where does the value of `bit_cnt` come from?

Comment: Also, please ignore what I outputted pertaining to 32 bit values as I am just focusing on the 64 bit values. I kept only the code pertaining to be 64 bit values.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the bit count to generate a mask. If you want a bit count greater than can be filled by `RAND_MAX`, implement another random function as I commented earlier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    int bit_cnt = 10;
    unsigned mask = 0;
    int i;
    int num;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < bit_cnt; i++)
        mask = (mask << 1) | 1;

    printf ("For bit_cnt=%d, mask=0x%X\n\n", bit_cnt, mask);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        num = rand() & mask;
        printf("Random number 0x%0*X\n", 1+(bit_cnt-1)/4, num);
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
For bit_cnt=10, mask=0x3FF

Random number 0x327
Random number 0x39C
Random number 0x1B1
Random number 0x088
Random number 0x26E
```